# Installing composer on ubuntu 16.4 : file could not be downloaded

Tags: composer-php

I am getting this error while installing composer (`sudo composer install`).
Can anyone help me out?

```
Cannot create cache directory /home/tanmay/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
```

Cannot create cache directory /home/tanmay/.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded:
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```